# Change passwd in second console

Tags: sudo, password, passwd

I faced with strange case with changing passwd:

0) sudoers has line "*Defaults ignore_dot,env_reset,passwd_timeout=1,timestamp_timeout=5*"

1) login in 2 console with same user01.

2) in both console do "sudo CMD" to save passwd and console don't ask passwd every time. See "timestamp_timeout=5" option.

3) in first console do "sudo passwd user01" and change passwd. Comand does not ask old passwd.

4) in second console do "sudo passwd user01" and change passwd. **Comand does not ask new passwd**.

Is there any way to save passwd for some time and protect from this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?  In both 3) and 4) you're running `passwd` as root and that user can change anyone's password.  Running it without `sudo` will cause it to ask for user01's current password, which I think is the behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: In step 3 passdw is changed. But in step 4 is used old passwd saved in step 2 - NEW passwd is NOT required after it is changed in other console.

Comment: No password is *saved*. The `sudo` session is just still *valid* / *active* due to the configured timeout. This is why `sudo` is not prompting for (the new) password again.

Comment: Yes, sudo session is still valid. Thanks for correct description.So is it possible turn all sudo sessions off after password was changed?

Comment: Yes, after changing the password, run `sudo -K` to forget the credentials.  `sudo` will ask for a password the next time it's used.